# How do I compress the contents of a folder using 'tar' over SSH?

Tags: unix, ssh, compression, tar

How do I compress the contents of a folder using the `tar` command on an Unix system over SSH?

Comment: Sounds like a question for Server Fault (http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: @RonK: Could you explain why? Because it sure doesn't belong there...

Comment: Because that is where I post such questions :-) . Any way - this comment was added before the question was migrated.

Answer (score 5):

From `tar --help`:

```
Examples:
  tar -cf archive.tar foo bar  # Create archive.tar from files foo and bar.
  tar -tvf archive.tar         # List all files in archive.tar verbosely.
  tar -xf archive.tar          # Extract all files from archive.tar.
```

So just use `tar -cf archiveName.tar folderName`.

Answer (score 2):

If the content you want to archive is in the home directory of the user - it should be:

```
ssh login_name@hostname 'tar cvf archive-name *'
```

If you need to navigate somewhere, try this:

```
ssh login_name@hostname 'cd some-dir;tar cvf archive-name *'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compress it, add the -z or -j arguments to the recommendations above.

```
ssh user@host 'tar -C direcotry -czf archivename.tar.gz files/directory'
```